# Difference between using Generics and Literal type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i'm trying to understand Generics. Just saw this code:

```js
export type ModelCtor<M extends Model> = typeof Model & { new(): M };
```

And i've tried use it:

```js
// Ok
import type { Model, ModelCtor } from 'sequelize';

const isExistsValidator = (model: ModelCtor<Model>, field: string) => { ... }
```

But, this case does not work:

```js
// Strange error inside function body, not important, just types are not compatible
import type { Model, ModelCtor } from 'sequelize';

const isExistsValidator = <M extends Model>(model: ModelCtor<M>, field: string) => { ... }
```

Generics M extends Model (abstract class), all his public properties, methods etc, but these types aren't compatible.

Why?
What is difference between these ways?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what's going wrong without more code, but `typeof Model` doesn't make sense.  `Model` is already a type here and you probably want `M` rather the `Model` anyways.  If you change it to `export type ModelCtor<M extends Model> = M & { new(): M };`, does that fix anything for you?

Comment: @LindaPaiste, ```export type ModelCtor<M extends Model> = M & { new(): M };``` it's a part sequelize  (third party). ```typeof Model``` here for a static methods (i pass class, not instance). Generally, i want to know, what is difference between ```<M extends Model>(model: M)``` and ```(model: Model)```, both cases gets object (instance class, that extends Model) ?